# curl cannot download file - response is empty

Tags: curl

If I put this url in a web browser I can read it:

https://bitbucket.org/teros/vcs-hooks/raw/master/clone-and-install.sh

but if I try to download with curl:

```
curl  https://bitbucket.org/teros/vcs-hooks/raw/master/clone-and-install.sh -o x.sh
```

I get nothing - perhaps I need to use my credentials? is there a way to configure that w/o having to use at the command line, using SSH + cURL?

Comment: Use `-v` to check out the response. Often you need to add something, for example `-L` to make curl follow redirects.

Comment: nothing happens? i get a http 404 error both in curl and the browser. do as Stenberg said, add -v and dump the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an auth issue. To add the right headers to the request, use:

```
curl -u "$user:$password" https://bitbucket.org/teros/vcs-hooks/raw/master/clone-and-install.sh -o x.sh
```

which mostly adds a header to the request like

```
Authorization: Basic base64('user:pass')
```